# How to express the oscillator equation $y'' + 3y'+2y=\cos(t)$ as a first order system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone please help me express this oscillator equation $y'' + 3y'+ 2y= \cos{(t)}$ as a first order system?

I also need to plot an approximate solution curve for the initial condition $x_0 = 5, y_0=1$. I was asked to create a Maple Worksheet and graph multiple initial conditions but I am having a hard time starting on this problem.

I tried to solve this by replacing $y' = V$.
So that $V' + 3V + 2y = \cos(t)$

$v' = -3V - 2y + \cos(t)$

But I cant get two differential equations.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Well, start by letting $x_1=y$ and $x_2=y'$. Then $x_1'=y'=x_2$ and $x_2'=y''=\cos t-3y'-2y=\cos t -3x_2-2x_1$. Now we have the first order system 
\begin{align*}
&x_1'=x_2\\
&x_2'=\cos t-3x_2-2x_1.
\end{align*}

In case you wanted to know how to solve the actual equation: Note that the characteristic polynomial of the equation is $r^2+3r+2=(r+1)(r+2)$, which has roots $r=-1$ and $r=-2$. Thus, solutions of the associated homogeneous equation have the form $y_h = C_1e^{-t}+C_2e^{-2t}$. Using the method of undetermined coefficients, we find that a particular solution of the given differential equation is $y_p=1/10(\cos t +3 \sin t)$. So the general solution is

\begin{align*}
y = C_1e^{-t}+C_2e^{-2t} + \frac{1}{10}\left(\cos t+3 \sin t\right). 
\end{align*}